# Using Python Click within a class

Tags: python, python-click

I've got an old flashcards app that I made that I've repurposed for some aws cert study. I wrote this years ago and overhauled that code, and one of those changes involved using `click` over `argparse`, but I'm having some issues using `click`. My code is below (minus a couple of extra functions):

The idea is that `load_deck()` needs to read the `file` argument. The way that I was trying to do it is pass `load_deck()` the `file` argument through `main()`

Finally, running this code states that within the `Flashcards().main()` call, `main()` is missing a positional argument self. I think this is a problem with the way I'm using `click`.

```
import os
import random
import sys

import click
import keyboard
import ruamel.yaml


class Flashcards:
    """
    pass
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
        self.card = ['key', 'value']

    def load_deck(self, file):
        """
        pass
        """
        with open(file, mode='r') as deck:
            self.deck = self.deck.load(deck)

    @click.command()
    @click.option('-f', '--file', default='aws.yaml', help='specifies yaml file to use')
    @click.option('-r', '--reverse', default=False, help='displays values prompting user to guess keys')
    def main(self, file, reverse):
        """
        pass
        """
        self.load_deck(file)
        if reverse is True:
            self.deck = [
                [card[1], card[0]
                 ] for card in self.deck]

        os.system('clear')
        print('Press [SPACEBAR] to advance. Exit at anytime with [CTRL] + [C]\n'
              'There are {} cards in your deck.\n'.format(len(self.deck)))
        try:
            while True:
                self.read_card()
                self.flip_card()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # removes '^C' from terminal output
            os.system('clear')
            sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Flashcards().main()
```

The program reads a yaml file in the following format (it was previously a spanish flashcard app):

```
bajar: to descend
borrar: to erase
contestar: to answer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click isn't naturally designed to work this way, see for example [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/601) which also includes some workarounds by folks in the comments if you want to go that route.

In your case, you could just yoink `main` out of the class and have it instantiate `Flashcards` for you:

```
@click.etc.
def main(file, reverse):
    f = Flashcards()
    f.load_deck(file)
    # And so on, using 'f' instead of 'self'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:

```
import click

class Stub:
    pass    


viking = click.make_pass_decorator(Stub,ensure=True)
@click.group()
@viking 
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx,_):
    ctx.obj = Viking()


class Viking(Stub):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Thor"

    @cli.command()
    @viking 
    def plunder(self):
        print(f"{self.name} attacks")

    @cli.command()
    @viking 
    def sail(self):
        print("whoosh")


cli()
```